# How to select a text from a web page and then copy paste it

Tags: select, copy, qtp

I need to select some text from a web page and then copy it using Ctrl-C. I know I can use send keys for Ctrl-C but how do I select the text from web page? The requirement is that I don't just check the `roproperty` I need to select(highlight) the text on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to get text from a web page using UFT is not via <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> but via UFT's built in methods.

- Select a test object and use it's `GetROProperty "innertext"` function
- Use an text (or text area) [output value](http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=70)

As for clipboard, do you really need to put the text in the clipboard? Usually variables and output parameters are the way you want to go.

If you *do* want to interact with the system's clipboard you can use `Mercury.Clipboard` supplied by UFT

```
Set cb = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard")
cb.SetText "This is easier than Ctrl-C"
```